# How can I tell when Facebook applications are spamming my friends?

Tags: facebook, notifications

There's nothing I hate more than receiving spammy notifications from other people's applications on facebook.  However, Sometimes I come across a useful application that I authorize to interact with my facebook account and I cannot tell if it subsequently sends out the same bothersome notifications to my friends.  Is there a way to track what an application is sending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a second account just for the purpose of monitoring how your own account is perceived by other people. It's not the best method but it should give you the most accurate judgement.